# Adding new menu item to a menu bar defined in plugin.xml programmatically in RCP application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse rcp application, with menu extension.
There is one menu item "File"

Now I want to add a new menu item from one of the  views (I know this is a wrong design, just want to test it)

in the method createPartControl of my class that extends  ViewPar, I have:

```
Menu menuBar =  parent.getShell().getMenuBar(); //I get the Menu that contains File
MenuItem editMenuItem = new MenuItem(menuBar, SWT.CASCADE);

editMenuItem.setText("Edit");
Menu editMenu = new Menu(parent.getShell(), SWT.DROP_DOWN);
editMenuItem.setMenu(editMenu);
```

When in Debug I watch the `parent.getShell().getMenuBar()`
I get:

> Menu {File, Edit}

But in application window I see only File menu.

Comment: How is your RCP creating the main menu? Are you using an `ActionBarAdvisor`? The main menu is normally managed by a `MenuManager` and won't let you add things this way.

Comment: yes, I have ApplicationActionBarAdvisor. so what are my options?

Comment: You would normally use the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point

Comment: Yes, this is my question, how to add another menu to menubar that was added as extensionpoint programmatically

Answer (score 2):

To do this programatically rather than via an extension point it looks like you have to use `IMenuService` and add a contribution factory:

```java
IMenuService menuService = (IMenuService)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IMenuService.class);

menuService.addContributionFactory(factory);
```

`factory` is a class derived from `AbstractContributionFactory` which provides the menu items.

This example is from http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/Search_Menu

```java
AbstractContributionFactory searchContribution = new AbstractContributionFactory(
           "menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=navigate") {
       public void createContributionItems(IMenuService menuService,
               List additions) {
           MenuManager search = new MenuManager("Se&arch",
                   "org.eclipse.search.menu");

           search.add(new GroupMarker("internalDialogGroup"));
           search.add(new GroupMarker("dialogGroup"));
           search.add(new Separator("fileSearchContextMenuActionsGroup"));
           search.add(new Separator("contextMenuActionsGroup"));
           search.add(new Separator("occurencesActionsGroup"));
           search.add(new Separator("extraSearchGroup"));

           additions.add(search);
       }

       public void releaseContributionItems(IMenuService menuService,
               List items) {
           // nothing to do here
       }
   };

menuService.addContributionFactory(searchContribution);
```